# how to fix Json crashing in swift 2.3 and XCode 8.1

Tags: ios, json, swift

```
Reverse Geocode Response = {
    error = "Unable to geocode";
} 

Reverse Geocode Response = {
    address =     {
        city = "San Francisco";
        country = "United States of America";
        "country_code" = us;
        county = "San Francisco City and County";
        electronics = "Apple Store";
        neighbourhood = Chinatown;
        pedestrian = "Stockton Street";
0postcode = 94104;
        state = California;
    };
    boundingbox =     (
        "37.7857515",
        "37.7859644",
        "-122.4066919",
        "-122.406347"
    );
    "display_name" = "Apple Store, Stockton Street, Chinatown, San Francisco, San Francisco City and County, California, 94104, United States of America";
    lat = "37.7858585";
    licence = "Data \U00a9 OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright";
    lon = "-122.406519260264";
    "osm_id" = 147689077;
    "osm_type" = way;
    "place_id" = 97545943;
}
```

i got success and fail response from API

```
 do {
                let result = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(response, options:.AllowFragments)
               // print("Reverse Geocode Response = \(result) ")

                 if result != nil {

                    let address:Dictionary = result!["address"]  as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
                    if address.count > 0 {

                        country = address["country"] as! String  //country_code
                        postalCode = address["postcode"] as! String

                        print("Country = \(country) ,Postal Code = \(postalCode)")

                    }
                 }else{
                    print("Error")
                }

            }catch{
                print("Error with Json \(error)")
            }
```

i got crash failed response time crashing.
please help to find that crash.

when i got  error = "Unable to geocode"; this response i got error
HOW TO RESOLVE THIS KIND OF SITUATION
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post the error message?

Comment: Remember, every use of `!` in your code means "crash here".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use `!` and `as!` unless you are completely sure you have the exact types you are casting into or the values under the `!` are not nil. In your example you have `as!` everywhere to get values out of the dictionary while you don't have these values so everything crashes. A proper way would be to:

```
// Ensure you have a valid json and the result is not empty
guard let json = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(response, options:.AllowFragments), 
result = json as? [String: Any] where !result.isEmpty else { 
print("Error while parsing \(response)") // Parsing to json failed
    return
}
// Try to get address out
guard let address = json["address"] as? [String: Any] where     !address.isEmpty,
    country = address["Country"] as? String,
    postalCode = address["postcode"] as? String else {
    print("Error") // There is no address, country or postcode
    return
}
// Here you have your address, country and postalCode
```